# how can i pass a date formate in agenda jobs

Tags: npm, agenda

```
const mongoconection =url;

const agenda = new Agenda({
  db: {
    address: mongoconection,
    collection: "agendajobs",
    option: { useUnifiedTopology: true }
  }
});

new Promise(resolve=> agenda.once('ready', resolve));

agenda.define("say hello", job => {
  console.log('hello');
});

(async function() {
  await agenda.start();

  await agenda.schedule(4/2/2020, 'say hello');
  //repeat every
})();
```

how can I pass the dynamic date to the agenda?``
it's falling if I give in this formate 4/2/2020
If I give 5 minutes  or even once a week if working
can  anyone  help me how to give time and specified date

Answer (score 0):

Since `schedule(when, name, [data])` as [per the documentation](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#schedulewhen-name-data)

> [s]chedules a job to run `name` once at a given time. `when` can be a **`Date`** or a `String` such as `tomorrow at 5pm`.

You need to provide a `Date` object instead of `String`.
The way to do it as per [Date MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values) is `new Date(2020, 1, 4)` (assuming you meant February and not April) so your line could be:

```
agenda.schedule(new Date(2020, 1, 4), 'say hello');
```